# Why is the friction force on the bed opposite of the gravity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

[image]

So here is a simple problem and here is a diagram that I find found online.
Why is the frictional force pointing downwards. I mean I get the correct answer if I follow this diagram and math checks out but intuitively. I thought the frictional force should be acting against the person falling off the bed due to downward gravity so I thought, frictional force should be pointing upwards NOT downwards. Can someone explain why? The questions asks for the smallest angle  at which the person will begin to slip off.
**correct answer is provided in the bottom for your reference**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I doubt that you would get the correct answer if you took the frictional force as downward unless you made a sign error somewhere. But you'd have to post more details of your calculation.

Comment: I think you're not taking into account the *centripetal force* acting on the man, needed to keep him rotating. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force

Comment: @Gert so are you saying centripetal force results in pushing the man up ward and as a result you would have the frictional force acting in the downward direction?

Comment: @Gert Do you mean in terms of determining the direction of friction?

Comment: @CuriousJ It depends on how fast the rotation is

Comment: @AaronStevens: yes. Which way the friction force points depends on all forces, he can't just leave one type of force out.

Comment: @Aaron Stevens so for other questions like this how would you draw the free body diagram if it depends on rotational speed. Wouldn't the direction be arbitrary. How would you be able to draw before hand and draw frictional force in the correct direction?

Comment: @CuriousJ: the direction of the friction force can initially be chosen arbitrarily. Once you've got the force diagram, apply $\Sigma F_x=0$ and $\Sigma F_y=0$ to calculate all forces you didn't know yet. If you find that $F_f<0$ that means you chose the 'wrong' direction for $F_f$. For problems like this, the correct direction of $F_f$ must be calculated from all other applied forces.

Comment: @Gert I am going to try out this problem with opposite direction for the Frictional force just to see if i get the same 'magnitude of the force' but thanks for your input I believe I understand your point.

Comment: @Gert is right. If you put friction going the wrong way then you will just end up with an extra negative sign floating around

Comment: Obviously, if you are looking for the smallest angle, you are only interested in keeping him from slipping off to upper right the way they have drawn $\theta$.  Falling down is not what the problem is asking.

Comment: In other words they are asking how flat you can get that table, not how upright it can be, so the friction force is drawn correctly for that case.

Comment: This problem is not really much different to problems in which a car is turning a corner on a banked track.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose there is no rotational motion. Then the frictional force must point upwards along the plane to keep the person from falling.

Now consider the situation when there is no friction and angular speed of rotation is very high. In the rotating frame, the centrifugal force will point outwards and its component along the plane will be higher (when angular speed is high enough) than the component of gravity downward along the plane. (You could do the whole calculation from inertial frame without invoking pseudo forces, but the situation be harder to visualize). If you turn on friction at this moment, it will point downwards in order to resist the upward motion of the man.

So, for low angular velocities, friction will point upward, and gradually to zero at a certain angular velocity (you can show that this angular speed is given by $\omega^2  = g \tan \theta /R$, where $R$ is the radius of the motion of the center of mass), and for higher angular velocities friction will point downward.

Comment: I think you mean friction is upwards in the no rotation situation

Comment: @triatticus edited